# Al referenciar a una variable de una clase: no guarda datos

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Cuando creo mi clase, creo una variable llamada

```
self.canvas_height= self.canvas.winfo_height()
```

en la cual almaceno el número resultado de un método que invoco. Hasta ahí bien pero luego de esa misma clase creo una función `dibujar` en donde en algún momento intento llamar a variable `self.canvas_height` y no funciona...

PERO estuve probando con la segunda variable `width` y en lugar de invocar los datos mediante la variable, me dije Ok probemos llamando a la función directamente, en este caso funcionó.

Mi duda es ¿por qué no funciona en el caso de Height cuando llamo a la variable?

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random

class pelota:
        def __init__(self,canvas,color):

            self.canvas_height= self.canvas.winfo_height()
            self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        def dibujar(self):

            if pos[2]>=self.canvas.winfo_width():


            if pos[3]>=self.canvas_height:
```

Comment: No tienes en tu clase una variable que sea self.canvas en teoría te debe fallar lo de tu método `__init__`

Comment: Antes de inicializar las propiedades `self.canvas_height = ...` haz `self.canvas = canvas`

Comment: Este código ni reproduce el problema que tienes ni nos ayuda a saber el motivo de que no te funcione el código que ejecutas. Revisa las instrucciones sobre [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en el metodo **init**.

Primero:
-Estas enviando self (instancia de la clase), canvas (asumo que es un objeto canvas), color (no lo utilizas. ¿?).

Por tanto al declarar:

```
self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height() # Esta mal porque no existe self.canvas
#No existe niguna variable self.canvas, no ha sido declarada aún.
```

Solución:
Declarar la variable:

```
self.canvas = canvas # canvas = objeto canvas que envias.
```

O utilizar el objeto canvas que envías directamente.

```
self.canvas_height = canvas.winfo_height()
```